# Why does a member function pointer have a type based on the class where the function actually declared?

Tags: c++

Look at this snippet:

```
struct A {
    void fn();
};

struct B: A {
};

void f() {
    auto x = &B::fn;
}
```

Here, `x` gets a type of `void (A::*)()`, despite the fact that I've written `&B::fn`.

If I added `fn` into `B`, then type of `x` would be `void (B::*)()`.

So, type of `&B::fn` changes whether B has a `fn`, or not.

What is the rationale behind this behavior? I find it surprising.

Why does this matter? Suppose this: programmer X creates `A` and `B`, like in my example. Programmer Y uses `&B::fn`, and uses the class-part of its type for something (like a parameter to a template, whatever). Then programmer X realizes, that he needs some extra functionality in `fn`, so he overrides it. Now, programmer Y's code can be broken, as type of `&B::fn` have changed.

Comment: When `fn` is overridden, the class interface will change. Programmer Y will have to recompile and the type will be correct again.

Comment: This seems like a consistent behavior. Programmer Y's code would be broken if `fn` is removed or renamed as well.

Comment: @VTT: yes, but usually adding an override for a function doesn't break anything. When one removes/renames a function, expects compile time errors. When adds an override, doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the subject of [CWG issue 203](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#203) and [EWG issue 89](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-closed.html#89). Initially, the rationale was to allow as much code as possible to be valid:

> **Notes from 04/00 meeting:**
>
> The rationale for the current treatment is to permit the widest possible use to be made of a given address-of-member expression. Since a pointer-to-base-member can be implicitly converted to a pointer-to-derived-member, making the type of the expression a pointer-to-base-member allows the result to initialize or be assigned to either a pointer-to-base-member or a pointer-to-derived-member. Accepting this proposal would allow only the latter use.

Later, after the problems caused by it had become more obvious, it was too late to fix:

> **Additional note, April, 2015:**
>
> EWG has determined that the utility of such a change is outweighed by the fact that it would break code. See EWG issue 89.

Comment: That's funny: "EWG thought that the change to existing semantics would practically require a time machine, and noted that these semantics didn't appear by accident" :)

Comment: hvd, btw, how did you find this information? Just with google, or do you have some background information, where to search for this? Some of my questions would be unnecessary, if I knew, how to search for these kind of information.

Comment: And I'd like to congratulate you... just 100 reps, and you'll have 100k!

Comment: @geza Thank you. I had a suspicion it would have been brought up at one point so just opened the core issue list and searched for `::*`. It didn't take long to go over all the results.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main idea comes from that usual "B is A" class inheritance definition. You can rephrase it for member functions like "functions of A are functions of B", however statement with flipped A and B position is correct only for some items, that is "only some functions of B are functions of A". So `B::fn` fits into this category of functions of B that are functions of A. By writing function `fn` in class B we at the same time move `B::fn` out of this category into category of functions of B that are not functions of A.

This allows one to check whether class overrides some method of base class:

```
const bool fn_is_overriden{::std::is_same<decltype(&A::fn), decltype(&B::fn)>::value};
```

Comment: Is this the reason for it, or a consequence of it? The latter seems more likely to me.

Answer (score 0):

In most ways, a member function is like a free function with an implicit object argument. So this code:

```
struct A {
    void fn();
};
```

is very similar to:

```
struct A {};
void A_fn(A* this_);
```

For example, overload resolution between member functions and free functions is defined in this way, so that all of the functions can be ranked on the same footing.

When you inherit a member (variable or function),  you inherit that function as it is. Inheritance doesn't define new functions or variables.  All it does is create names in the derived class that refer to the existing members of the base class.

You've still got `A_fn(A* this)`, just that it is accessible from B's scope.  The access rules for inheritance apply to the inherited names only, they don't change any properties of the member.